Text file remove all https:// [view] and .?,:...! plus add a comma after every word or character block (numbers)

Input:

The sun ... rises in the: East! (https://www.youtube.com/123).  Smile! Yes!! [view] ...  The sun ... sets in the: west! (https://www.youtube.com/456). Smile! Yes!! [view] ...

Desired Output:

The, sun, rises, in, the, East, youtube.com/123,  Smile, Yes  The, sun, sets, in, the, west, youtube.com/456 Smile, Yes


I have researched this tons, and for the removal of certain text I have found this, however all of them will take each and every v, i, etc. and replace it in the document, whereas what I am after is every instance of [view]:


$content = Get-Content "D:\input.txt"
$content | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "[view]", " "} | Set-Content "D:\output.txt"



(Get-Content input.txt) -replace '[view]', ' ' | Out-File -encoding ASCII output.txt



Get-ChildItem d:\ -Filter *.txt | Foreach-Object{(Get-Content $_.FullName) | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "[view]", " "} | Set-Content $_.FullName}



I have tried quotations and other items (to remove the brackets [ ] view, and the other headache is the code doesn't like the ?.:...;! for removing them. For the insertion of commas after every word/number, I am only finding sed and the like, but nothing simpler.   (solved comma problem and solved removal of most punctuation and https:// thanks to Mr.Key7!) Still working on [view] specifically the brackets (managed to take out view but still have [ ]).

Please edit your question and add an example of your data and expected result.

@ReddyLutonadio I prefixed it with the input and desired output, to the human mind this isn't as complicated as it appears to be becoming with the code, I appreciate any and all suggestions!

sed gets complex with regular expression, but for mass replacements, it's very effective. When I've had to do so, I'll have the sed man page pulled up in one browser window and a man page for regex in the other and write the command by going back and forth

$content = Get-Content -path "D:\input.txt"
$removed = @('(https://www.', '[view]', ').', '...', '!', ':')
$removed | ForEach-Object {
    $content = $content.Replace($_,'')
}
$content | ForEach-Object {
    (($_.Split().Trim()) -ne '') -Join ', '
} | Set-Content "D:\output.txt"

Another Short Format:
$c = cat "D:\input.txt"
$r = '(https://www.', '[view]', ').', '...', '!', ':'
$r | %{$c = $c.Replace($_,'')}
$c | %{(($_.Split().Trim())-ne'') -Join ', '} >"D:\output.txt"

Another way:
Get-Content "D:\input.txt" | Select-String -Pattern 'The|sun|rises|in|the|East|west|Smile|Yes|youtube\.com\/\d+' -AllMatches | ForEach-Object {$_.Matches.Value -join ', '} | Out-File -FilePath "D:\output.txt"

gc "D:\input.txt" | sls 'The|sun|rises|in|the|East|west|Smile|Yes|youtube\.com\/\d+' -AllMatches | % {$_.Matches.Value -join ', '} >"D:\output.txt"


Thanks a million! it seems to work about 90% of what I am looking for but that pesky [view] that is on every line WILL NOT disappear.  From my tinkering I am guessing the [ ] is the problem and I did manage to the the view gone but the [ ] stay.  There has to be an override or some way to tell the code that a [ ] in the text is not a command or exempt character.  Please help on that, but thank you Mr.Key7 and others for your advice!

Mr.Key7 thank you for the updated last 2 codes, however this will be a 2 or 3 page document so individually going for each term to keep won't be useful but I will keep those codes if they can be used for other things.  Still having a problem getting the code to remove the brackets [ ] any ideas?

$r = '(https://www.', 'view', ').', '...', '!', ':', '[', ']' you can modify this
